# Excel VBA kinda Reverse Lookup - any better options?

Tags: vba, excel, lookup

**Setup**

I have two sheets with one sheet containing the textual data and another containing the look up data.

[image]

**Problem**

I need to determine if a line contains a matching countryname and extract its corresponding id from sheet 2. This is reverse of VLOOKUP or Match function where I am looking for sheet 1 data in sheet 2.

Any easy way to do this other than looping through the entire set of sheet 2 data for each of the lines in sheet 1 data?

Comment: If there was some kind of delimiter or tag to show the start and end of the country name it would be much easier.  Since there is not, youll have to do a `Find` for each item in your lookup list.

Comment: +1 for a good Q.  Using VBA perhaps experiment with a RegEx to identify capitalised words from Sheet 1 Data rows and do a Find in Sheet 2 Data for each of them.  There will be some redundancy but, from your illustrative text, not as much as looping though the entire set of Sheet 2 Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
=LOOKUP(9.9E+300,SEARCH(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$2,A25),Sheet2!$A$1:$A$25)
```

Change $25 to your exact range, or use named ranges. This will return the ID if found, #N/A if not found, and if there is more than one match you will only get the last match.

EDIT: If you want the first match you could use this formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$25,MATCH(1=1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$25,A1)),0,0),),1)
```

EDIT II: How this works

The `SEARCH`function in both examples says find the starting position of any of the words in the range (array)  `Sheet2!$B$1:$B$25` for cell `A1`

In the first example `LOOKUP` will then look for a number (the row number) less than 9.9E+300 and return the value from the row in the result vector (this is why it returns the last matched result).

In the second example `MATCH(1=1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$25,A1)),0,0)` will determine the row number by finding the first true (1=1) in the array produced by the `INDEX` function. Then the outer `INDEX` function returns the adjacent column (the ID).

Comment: In both cases change SEARCH to FIND for an exact match.

Comment: I was able to get what I was expecting, using this!

Comment: How did this work? It would be nice if you explained the logic behind this combination. I have seen Index Matches. However this does the reverse and uses Search function.

Comment: One more thing. I tried this on a sheet with 50000 rows (sheet 2) with this formula applied across each text in sheet 1. It is taking forever to complete the calculation. Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to speed up the built in function. I think it is slow because you are using Excel with an array of 50,000 items. If it was me I'd be looking at building a custom solution in vba or .NET if speed is an issue. You have 50,000 countries?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a worksheet formula.

I chose to use a Table and structured references, but you can use other methods:

On sheet1:

```
B2:    =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Countries[CountryName],A2)),Countries[ID]),"")
```

or

```
B2:  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$258,A2)),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$258),"")
```

will return the ID or a blank.

This formula is normally entered. And LOOKUP will ignore the div/0 errors, matching the 1/True (=1) and returning the value in the corresponding position from result_vector

Comment: I tried this method and it was returning 0 for some reason...will investigate further...Happy Friday!